# object is saved in global variable but is displaying undefined

Tags: javascript, object, undefined

I am a little stuck and would like to get some help. I have two html files index.html and welcome.html. I also have two js files, script.js and welcome.js. My problem is, I am trying to display an object but it is displaying undefined.

I am using firebase google sign in and I am trying to display the name of the user but when I do that in welcome.html, i get undefined as a result.

Here is my script.js code:

```
var username;
login.addEventListener('click' ,function(){
  if(!firebase.auth().currentUser)
    {
        const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then((result) => {
            var token = result.credential.accessToken;
            window.sessionStorage.setItem("token", token);
            console.log(result);
            username = result.user.displayName;
            console.log("Success!");
            doWelcome();
        
        }).catch((error) => {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            var email = error.email;
            var credential = error.credential;
            if(errorCode === 'auth/account-exists-wtih-different-credential'){
                alert("You have already signed up with a different auth provider for that email");
            }else{
                console.error(error);
            }
        });
    }else{
        firebase.auth().signOut();
    }
})

var doWelcome = function(){
    window.location.replace("welcome.html");
    //alert(username);
}
```

welcome.js code:

```
const welcomeTitle = document.getElementById('welcomeTitle'); //from welcome.html
welcomeTitle.style.fontSize ="50px";
welcomeTitle.innerHTML = "Welcome, " + username;
```

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: A global JS variable defined on a different HTML page cannot be accessed directly. You can save it into localStorage in script.js and load it from there in welcome.js.

Comment: Using sessionStorage is better. In script.js: `sessionStorage.setItem("username", username);`, and in welcome.js: `const username = sessionStorage.getItem("username");`

Comment: @kol Thank you so much! It worked!

Comment: You are welcome!